# Java TripleDES PKCS5Padding decryption to C# - bad data / padding error

Tags: encryption, cryptography, tripledes

I'm trying to write the C# equivalent for the following Java code:

```java
protected static final String DES_ECB_PKCS5PADDING = "DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding";

 public static String decryptValueDirect(String value, String key)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            GeneralSecurityException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(value);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(DES_ECB_PKCS5PADDING);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, convertSecretKey(key.getBytes()));
        byte[] decryptedValue = cipher.doFinal(bytes);

        String nstr =  new String(decryptedValue);
        return nstr;
    }
protected static SecretKey convertSecretKey(byte[] encryptionKey) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        if (encryptionKey == null || encryptionKey.length == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Encryption key must be specified");

        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(TRIPLEDES);
        KeySpec keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(encryptionKey);
        return keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    }
```

The source text is a base64 encoded, then encrypted and then base64 encoded for transport on a rabbit queue.  Our vendor who handles the encryption provided the above for decryption in Java, but has no idea about C#.

The only input on the encryption side is a key, a random string.  We use the same string for encryption/decryption 012345678901234567890123456789 in our dev env.  That is the only input, no salt, hashing (that i see) or pw iterations. The only requirement is that it is at least 24 chars long.

My C# code is below and a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BhhG5a) of my attempt is here.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Message Data value
        //We are using encrypted multibyte.     
        string myData = @"ROE8oYeV7B6faUsvfIx0Xe55vSs9IR5DlWGRbSM+lmKmLcaJsA13VudwWlAEYtLUD8+nMXShky0grSxsk0Z9cQe5V45XnAIfUhnyzI9a0jtMFC8XnIZ5dbclPO/V73QnieIZDkbNV5cPo3BM+l79ai96KB/gkF3xuerFPxvWejtPyWbOyO+FfNyFps4gAYDITsYIAEH39VP4eipmQ5zc18BA39lajQ3UaVewSxz7H+x3Ooe2SzJT/TQWRkioJSEFwexqzkHiLOQ0MOCIVD9xTWpLYnsL3LMwyF6H8f0PY4Fc57LVGhvUZ7dsB9NWUAnmG3uqbsonNFVhuXyvJTWNyFOHwFzOMx6XDLJJFHGZhaHg2VrescfnpUtonQY08RgojBngyJNRqK8URAvI3bqKq8Y7F/9HmEtMIIQe6KuuTmU=";
        string myKey = "012345678901234567890123456789";//Development Env Key.
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypt1:");
        string s = Decrypt1(myData, myKey);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string Decrypt1(string value, string decryptionKey)
    {
        string decryptString = "";
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tDESalg = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashMD5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        try
        {
            byte[] decodedData = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
            tDESalg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            tDESalg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;//According to MS, same as PKCS5PADDING

            byte[] Key = hashMD5Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decryptionKey));
            //byte[] IV = tDESalg.IV;
            byte[] IV = new byte[tDESalg.BlockSize / 8]; //The size of the IV property must be the same as the BlockSize property divided by 8

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(decodedData);
            var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, tDESalg.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            var reader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream);
            decryptString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            byte[] decryptData = Convert.FromBase64String(decryptString);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A Cryptographic error occurred: {0}", e.Message + e.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }

        return decryptString;
    }

}
```

Searching seems to point to the same answer, the key, encoding, ... all must be the same.  I just don't know what that would be the equivalent for the Java source provided. :)  Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: If you have a problem with your code, then you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. Help us help you without wasting time on guessing. Also, don't provide a link to your code. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code. Links break all the time and if it does, this question will lose all value.

Comment: Of course you realize that 3DES and ECB mode are a poor security choice.

Comment: Well, the key is decoded in a defective manner that loses half the entropy. However, to get the same effect in C# simply throw away the last 8 characters of the key, and decode the same way, using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(), and not using MD5.

Comment: @JamesKPolk You seem to think the key is not a hex representation. It is more likley a hex representation of a 2-key 3DES key, sometimes known as 2TDEA.

Comment: I think it was supposed to be a hex representation, but was decoded incorrectly. If the C# must match the defective Java code I am showing how to do so. Of course it's better not to do it wrongly, if that's possible.

Comment: This statement:
**"The only input on the encryption side is a key, a random string. We use the same string for encryption/decryption 012345678901234567890123456789. That is the only input, no salt, hashing (that i see) or pw iterations."**
 relates to the Encryption/Decryption key for encrypting/dencrypting replicator content shared. It is a random GUID string, but could be any string 24 chars long. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I already gave you the answer.

Comment: @zaph: I forgot to mention, I actually decrypted the string by treating the key the way I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MD5 has a 16-byte output, Triple DES (3DES) requires a 24-byte key. There is a key size mis-match.

The C# and Java key derivations are substantially different:

> C#:
>   `byte[] Key = hashMD5Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decryptionKey));`
>   returns 16-bytes.
>
> Java:
>   `SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(TRIPLEDES)`
>   returns 24-bytes.

There is a key option (2TDEA) where a 16-byte key is used and the first 8-bytes will be duplicated to create the last 8-bytes. NIST has deprecated this option.

Some implementations will accept a 16-byte key and extend the key to 24-bytes and **some will not**. You should provide all 24-bytes to 3DES, do not rely on an implementation to create the 24-byte key.

> Note: The question was updated so it is not clear that the the actual encrytpion key is derived.

Comment: The above is a great explanation of Jame's comment.  I followed what James K Polk wrote above and made this change:
From this:  byte[] Key = hashMD5Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decryptionKey));
To this:  **byte[] Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decryptionKey.Substring(0,24));**
It works now without an error.  Thank you Zaph and @James K Polk